# What type of Visual Studio website/project should I use?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanna build an online project by using ASP.NET.

It is an online timetable creator which takes the information from different schools, stored them in a DB then build a timetable object for each school.

First: what type of a website/project should I use in Visual Studio 2010?

Second: how I can store the timetable object -that made from C# class- and make reference to its school row in a DB? Thanks =')

Comment: your questions are not related, ask two questions instead of asking complex question )

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  Not sure I understand the question.  I'd use a typical ASP.NET Web Application project type.

As for the database question, I think you'll want to have a "School" table as well as a "Timetable" table.  Then you can create a linking table (something like "SchoolTimetable") which links one school's ID to a timetable's ID.  That would be the strict way to do it.  If it's a 1-to-1 relationship, however, you can simply have a TimetableID column in the school table, or vice-versa, a SchoolID column in the Timetable table.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Web Site project if your are planning to make rather simple than complex solution. It is at least easier to debug.